# Overlaying GeoJSON data in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Simply, I need to show the data on this web map with a simple popup of its attributes.
Data (Csv): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3fQ9_46L-O0WlZHUWZVczBfcWs/view?usp=sharing
Data:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3fQ9_46L-O0Q1haVlpwZVRLbGM/view?usp=sharing

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Tupche_Map</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-07I2e+7D8p6he1SIM+1twR5TIrhUQn9+I6yjqD53JQjFiMf8EtC93ty0/5vJTZGF8aAocvHYNEDJajGdNx1IsQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
   <!--Include Leaflet JavaScript file-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-A7vV8IFfih/D732iSSKi20u/ooOfj/AGehOKq0f4vLT1Zr2Y+RX7C+w8A1gaSasGtRUZpF/NZgzSAu4/Gc41Lg=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='js/tupche.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='js/village.js'></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
    <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
//JS and leaflet
var map = L.map('map', {
  'center': [5, 28],
  'zoom': 1,
  'layers': [
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      'attribution': 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
    })
  ]
}).setView([28.39, 84.12], 10);
//Add some GeoJson
L.geoJson(tupche).addTo(map);
```

Comment: And? do you get an error? which one?

Comment: how is tupche a geoJSON object? I can only see it as an external JS file in your in your index.html..

Comment: I don't get any error but in a map the data didn't appear

Comment: I just need simple web map with this data overlay in it